# Given $T$ an idempotent operator, why $R(T)=R(T^*)\implies T=T^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

The context of the problem I have is that $T$ is supposed to be an idempotent/projection operator. (Actually I'm trying to re-understand [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2937765/390226)[at 1. fifth line "*If...*"] I got about a month before)

---

About my current understanding: I'm really confused about that given an idempotent operator $T^2=T$, and combine with $T=T^*$ then it becomes an orthogonal projection operator.

I know a little about four fundamental subspaces and some properties about adjoint operator. But I didn't connect the dots to understand what happen when $T=T^*$ will make the $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ "orthogonal".

Since I don't fully understand the relation so I didn't assume $T$ to be idempotent in the following original proof and it's incorrect...

---

(*For $N(T)$ means the null space of $T$, while $R(T)$ means the range of $T$.*)
Let $T$ be a linear operator defined on an finite inner product space $V$. What I want to prove is that

\begin{align*}
R(T)=R(T^*)\implies T=T^*
\end{align*}

so $T$ is self-adjoint.

Assume $R(T)=R(T^*)$. Since

$$N(T)^\perp=R(T^*)=R(T)\\
R(T)^\perp=N(T^*)=R(T^*)$$

and by the fact that $V=W\oplus W^\perp$ where $W$ is any subspace of $V$

$$V=N(T)\oplus R(T)\\
V=N(T^*)\oplus R(T^*)$$

and $N(T^*)=R(T)^\perp=R(T^*)^\perp=N(T)$, so

$$N(T)=N(T^*)$$

but does this mean $T=T^*$? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the decomposition $V=N(T)\oplus R(T)$, and $N(T)=N(T^*)$ and $R(T)=R(T^*)$, you have enough to finish.

Given $x\in V$, write $x=v+w$, where $v\in N(T)$ and $w\in R(T)$.   There exist $u,u'\in V$ such that $w=Tu=T^*u'$.  We have 
$$Tx=T(v+w)=Tu=T^*u'=T^*(v+T^*u')=T^*(v+w)=T^*x.$$
Since $x\in V$ was arbitrary, $T=T^*$.

Comment: So only when $T$ is idempotent then $T=T^*\iff {N(T)=N(T^*)\lor R(T)=R(T^*)}$? And my intuition that $T=T^*$ will make subspace orthogonal is false?

Comment: Yes. For a counterexample, if $T$ is invertible then $T^*$ is invertible, and we have the $N(T)=N(T^*)=0$ and $R(T)=R(T^*)=V$, but $T$ need not be self-adjoint.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: Oh I get it... Really sorry, Iol...

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Is that the only counterexample? I mean I hope it's the only one... I want the statement in my first comment be a useful observation...

Comment: I can't really say that this is the only counterexample without thinking about this some more.  But I can say that $T$ being idempotent implies $T=T^*\iff {N(T)=N(T^*)\lor R(T)=R(T^*)}$ is still a nice observation to make.